# Update specific columns of dash datatable python

Tags: python

On dash I would like to update only 2 columns by real time values in every `n_intervals` of 1 minute. There are 6 columns in the data table, but I would like to update only 2 remaining should be as it is.

My code is the following:

```
@app.callback(Output('df_table', 'columns'),[Input('interval', 'n_intervals'),
               Input('df_table', 'data')])

def update_data_2(n_intervals,df):

    data_2 = pd.DataFrame(df)

    data_2=data_2[['A','B','C','D','E','F']]

    data_2['A']= real time values list

    data_2['B']=update values based on 'A' column
    return data_2[['A','B']]
```

While this is running, columns `'C'` to `'F'` should not change.
Please help me, when I run above code, it is giving me an error.

Comment: What is the error your code is giving you?

Comment: Error is that output is kind of dataframe and not JSON serializable. its not updating my daatable.